# Open html page fullscreen mode in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking a way to open html page in full screen mode but without user interaction. I have tested fullscreen API to open webpage in full screen but it needs a user interaction. Is it possible i can do it without user interaction like onbodyload etc. Currently i am getting a warning if i try to call fullscreen API onbodyLoad

```
Request for full-screen was denied because Element.mozRequestFullScreen() was not called from inside a short running user-generated event handler.
```

have any otherway to solve this.

Comment: Live with that, it's an useful feature unless you want spammers to be even more annoying...

Comment: maybe try listening to `document.onfocus` or any mouse movement

Comment: This can only been done by the client. Users has to save the page as a shortcut/web app which you could help create with a manifest file and only then it can start in fullscreen mode. The other option is launch the browser in fullscreen mode directly (aka: kiosk mode)